# Casting to a Generic Typed Object Using Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Can I cast an object from type `object` to `MyType<T>` using reflection if I don't know what T is until runtime?

Comment: Yes; but you wont be able to compile against if it the type isn't known till runtime.

Comment: Could you better specify your scenario?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Casting is a compile-time operation that requires a compile-time type.

Comment: As long as you define your `MyType<T>` as: `MyType<T> where T : object` you should not run into any problems, as T is defined for the compiler, and any object inherits from object.

Comment: No Aevitas, because there is no inheritance relation between say MyType<object> and MyType<string>. You cannot assign a MyType<string> to a MyType<object> variable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't *cast* to a type unknown at compile time.  Casting is really only useful as a compile-time construct, as you'd need to know the type in order to use it directly.

If your goal is to work with the object via Reflection, however, that's a different scenario.  In that case, you can use [Type.MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) to create the correct type for your object.

This will allow you to use reflection to work upon your object.

Comment: OK, but how will you access the members of the object created by reflection? You will need to no its type anyway. The casting problem remains.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes You need to know something about the class - but not its specific type.  As long as you know the name of a property or method, you can discover its types and call it, etc.  (I agree, in most cases, it's of little use - but there are times when this is very useful.)

Answer (score 1):

The trick in such situations, is to use a non-generic class with generic methods.

```
public class MyType
{
    public T GetResult<T>() {
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this happens at compile time. Generics give you the opportunity to create different "flavors" of a type or a method at compile time; but generics are **not** dynamic! Generics are type-safe and type safety can only be achieved at compile time (because it's the compiler who checks the type safety).